# Context.module fires blocks on access denied pages. How do I stop this?

Tags: 7

The context.module fires block regions on the access denied page if the condition for the context is path. I don't have much of a choice in triggers other than path for these pages. How to do I disable the side blocks? Is doing a page redirect to a custom 403 page a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Context Error](http://drupal.org/project/context_error), and set the proper condition.